# Is the Radical Circle always Orthogonal to other Circles?

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles

Wolfram**MathWorld** gives the following explanation for [Radical Circle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RadicalCircle.html):

> [image]
>
> The radical circle of three given circles is the circle having center at the radical center of the three circles and is orthogonal to all of them. (A circle with center at the radical center that is orthogonal to one of the original circles is always orthogonal to all three.)

Is the radical circle always orthogonal to other circles? Or it is orthogonal with all circles only when it is orthogonal with one circle? I am unable to clearly distinguish between these based on the given explanation.

Comment: Yes. The reason they added the terms in brackets is to clarify that you only need to ensure orthogonality to one of the circles to end up with the radical circle.

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof, Are there any other cases when the radical circle is not orthogonal to the given circles?

Comment: The definition explicitly states that the radical circle is *that* circle which has the radical center as center and is orthogonal to the given circles. It's impossible for it not to be orthogonal to the given circles by definition. There always exists one (and exactly one) such circle.

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof, Thank you. Do we have any special terms for circles which have the centre at the radical centre but is not orthogonal to the given circles?

Comment: I have no clue. I'd suppose not, since they'd be of little practical value.